# Angularjs select with count of filtred elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create select, which show count of elements in filter. Seems like that

[image]

**[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/g3QDBnKGx5TS0f9qDd42?p=preview)** is PlunkR with code, that i have wrote.  It's great make his job, but i cannot add count of `active/deactive` elements in select. How can I do this?
Thank's

Comment: thank's for editting post @Suren-Srapyan

Answer (score 0):

You can format the values before binding with the select options.

```
  <select ng-options="i as format(i) for i in statusList" ng-model="statusFilter">
</select>
```

The format function is,

```
  $scope.format = function(val) {
    return val.status + ' ' + $scope.objs.filter(function(state) {
      return state.status === val.value;
    }).length;
  }
```

Where the `$scope.objs` is the array of values which has `active/inactive` items.

[Here](https://embed.plnkr.co/JC29RsD62beNzgVa8YE4/) is the working plunkr